# Docker container exits immediately with error 145

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to containerize my .net5 web api to run in a linux container the whole day here is what i did...

so i auto generated the following Dockerfile with visual studio

---

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
# bunch of COPY instructions
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "myapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

*i've verified proper casing, so that's not the issue*

---

i successfully built the image using the following command

```
C:\SomeDir> docker build . -t myapp
```

---

the directory structure on the host looks as follows:

```
C:\SomeDir\Dockerfile
C:\SomeDir\docker-compose.yml
C:\SomeDir\MyApp\myapp.csproj
```

---

than i manualy created the following docker compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    image: myapp:latest
    ports: 
      - 34567:443
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:latest
    volumes:
      - myapp-neo4j-data:/var/lib/neo4j

volumes:
  myapp-neo4j-data:
```

---

and attempted to run it with the following command:

```
C:\SomeDir> docker-compose up
```

---

the neo4j container started without issues but my app container exited with the following error:

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
* You intended to execute a .NET program:
The application 'myapp.dll' does not exist.
* You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

---

than i tried changing the following line in my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
```

to this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS base
```

and got this error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
* You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
* You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-myapp.dll does not exist.
* You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

any help would be much appreciated, happy new year :)

Comment: What's in the `.` folder your docker-compose points to? Because whatever is in that folder is mounted to `/app` inside the container instead of what you copied in the Dockerfile and probably doesn't contain the dll.

Comment: thanks for responding tim, i've tried mounting different directories for example C:\SomeDir or C:\SomeDir\MyApp non have made a difference shouldn't the last two lines before the entrypoint in my Dockerfile take care of this?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled over the same issue. Removing the following fixed the issue for me:

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
```

Comment: Why did this work?

Comment: I think because my application lies in the /app folder